# Columns in the footer (React-bootstrap) are assembling vertically and I want the column should appear horizontally

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have added 3 columns and all are appearing vertically downwards (stacking), I want them to appear horizontally. My Footer doesn't looks like a footer anymore other elements,text of other container are also appearing on my footer.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <FooterContainer className="main-footer">
      <div className="footer-middle">
        <div classNames="container">
          <div clasName="row" display="flex">
            {/* {column 1} */}
            <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-4">
              <h4>lorem</h4>
              <ul className="list-unstyled">
                <li>
                  <a href="/"> Lorem ipsum </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/">Lorem ipsum </a>{" "}
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/">Lorem ipsum </a>{" "}
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/">Lorem ipsum </a>{" "}
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/">Lorem ipsum </a>{" "}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            {/* {column 2} */}
            <div clasName="row" display="flex">
              <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-4">
                <h4>lorem</h4>
                <ul className="list-unstyled">
                  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              {/* {column 3} */}
              <div clasName="row">
                <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-4">
                  <h4>lorem</h4>
                  <ul className="list-unstyled">
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                {/* {column 4} */}
              </div>
              {/* Footer bottom */}
              <div className="footer-bottom">
                <p className="text-xs-center">
                  &copy;{new Date().getFullYear()}
                  Reserved
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </FooterContainer>
  );
};

export default Footer;

const FooterContainer = styled.footer`
  .footer-middle {
    padding-top: 3rem;
    color: var(--mainWhite);
  }
  .footer-bottom {
    padding-top: 3rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
  }
   {
    ul li a {
      color: var(--mainGrey);
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  }
  ul li a:hover {
    color: var(--mainLightGrey);
  }
`;
```

*I have added bootstrap in my app.js file*
.Also let me know if I'm missing any modules to install or any other help would be really appreciable.
[linked my code on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-keller-lskjj?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: you should use one row with 3 columns inside it. (not 3 rows)

Answer (score 1):

you should use **1 row with 3 columns**. (not 3 rows with 3 columns)

working example:
[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-haze-23p0y?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: it worked thank you, Now I just want to align them.How to add space between them?

Comment: @atinbansal  I highly recommend you to use `offset classes` in bootstrap. [learn more](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid)

Comment: if it was helpful, don't forget to upvote and accept the best answer :)

Comment: Although my other elements i.e. elements of header file or other components are overlapping in footer component and I just wanted my components should work independently not overlapping any other's text or area. Help

Comment: if is possible, provide more details and show the snippets of your code.

Comment: I will add another query for that soon. Add me if possible .

Answer (score 0):

**You would need to import bootstrap.min.css to your code**

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

Working example:

[image: Edit zealous-sanne-644yt]

Comment: I have added this file on my app.js. Where I have imported all my components files too.

Comment: Have you installed [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction) following this guide?

Comment: Yes I have installed bootstrap and my other functions are working good except this grid system. I'm facing grid issue probably on every files.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using react-boostrap, you should try using the components as specified in the doc : https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/

```
<Container>
  <Row>
    <Col xs={4} sm={6} md={3}> Col 1</Col>
    <Col xs={4} sm={6} md={3}> Col 2</Col>
    <Col xs={4} sm={6} md={3}> Col 3</Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

Comment: shall I remove the className function and add this file independently?

Comment: Yes, for example if you specify `xs={4}` in the props, you don't need `className=col-xs-4`

Comment: it showing that col is undefined. Although I have realized that I have used 3 rows .I have just edited that and it works fine here? shall I need to arrange it more ?(i.e., use the method you mentioned )

Comment: import { Container, Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap'